# Is it possible to use an environment variable in the FROM instruction of a Dockerfile?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I want to make the `FROM` instruction in my `Dockerfile` dynamic based on an environment variable, so that I can build images based on different versions of a base image without having to change the `Dockerfile` itself. Here's an example of what I'm trying to do:

```
FROM php:${PHP_VERSION}-fpm
```

In this example, I want to use the `PHP_VERSION` environment variable to specify the version of the php image that my image should be based on. However, when I try to build my image using this Dockerfile, I get an error that says:

```
invalid reference format
```

Is it possible to use an environment variable in the `FROM` instruction of a `Dockerfile`? If so, how can I do it?

Comment: yes thank you  i was trying docker-compose up -d --build --build-arg PHP_VERSION=${PHP_VERSION}  it doesn't woek because a problem in my system, that's why i post the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, use `ARG` and `ENV`:

```
ARG PHP_VERSION
ENV PHP_VERSION ${PHP_VERSION}

FROM php:${PHP_VERSION}-fpm
```